# best practice for device with custom and standard mibs

Tags: snmp, mib

We have a device which has a custom MIB.
But it also includes some data from standard MIBs (notably UCD)

Now I could just tell my customers to load those OID seperatly or I could (this is possible if I'm not mistaken) include the MIB Tree (the parts I need) from UCD into my custom MIB.

Something like that

```
MyMIB
- MyOID1 
  - SubOID
- UCD-OID1
```

I couldn't find anything about this case.
Although I saw that UCD does for example include other MIBS (created by them).

So the question is.

*When I have a custom MIB and standard MIBS is it best practice to include the standard MIBS into my custom OID Tree or should they remain completly separate?*

From a convience standpoint I would argue it's better to include, but I'm an SNMP beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you use "We", I assume you do have some colleagues to explain that to you in details.

For your customers who are familiar with SNMP concepts, they just need the custom MIB document from you, but probably not the standard MIB documents. When they use a MIB compiler/browser to load that custom MIB document, the objects should be loaded successfully as the tool is usually able to find the standard MIB documents.

However, you'd better also make standard MIB documents available, as there can always be some customers that don't know much about SNMP.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately nobody of our team knows much about SNMP, but that's another story...
Goes like always, Featurerequest (SNMP) comes in, project manager says "sure no problem we can do it", Developers have to manage somehow.

When you say "make standard MIB.. available" do you mean just release the standard MIB File as a standalone file?

Comment: @Arikael. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/9226-mibs-9226.html#q3 You can learn from Cisco.